# Which if statement is better?

Tags: php, if-statement

Here are two examples:

example 1

```
if( $test['rank'] > 1 && $text == 'test' || $test['admin'] == 1 && $text == 'test'){
```

example 2

```
if( $text == 'test' && ( $test['rank'] > 1 || $test['admin'] == 1 ) ){
```

Even if both way seem to work, is there any difference except the way that they are written?

Comment: guess $text == 'test'  (You've forgot one = sign)

Comment: yes sorry i edited it but the question is there a difference between those 2 statement apart the fact that the first one is longer to write.

Comment: You've answered to Your own question. better do var_dump($text == 'test' && ( $test['rank'] > 1 || $test['admin'] == 1)  and var_dump($test['rank'] > 1 && $text == 'test' || $test['admin'] == 1 && $text == 'test')  if they are return same results in any variations of params so use shortest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, there is no difference except that the first one is a lot harder to read because of the lacking parenthesis.

Because > and == get evaluated before && and ||, you can write your code this way:

```
$p = $test['rank'] > 1;
$q = $text == 'test';
$r = $test['admin'] == 1;

if( $p && $q || $r && $q ) {
```

If you check [PHP operators precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), you have that && get evaluated before ||, so you have:

```
if( ( $p && $q ) || ( $r && $q ) ) {
```

so... $q must be meet in both expressions, making it equivalent to:

```
if( $q ) {
    if( $p || $r ) {
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if( $q && ( $p || $r ) ) {
```

replacing $p, $q and $r you finally get:

```
if( $text == 'test' && ( $test['rank'] > 1 || $test['admin'] == 1 ) ) {
```

tada!